# A couple of questions: 1. toggle pivot high and low function on or off. 2. change the label offset distance

Tags: plot, switch-statement, toggle, pine-script

I've tried editing the previous post to add this question, but I don't think anyone saw it, so here's a brand spanking new post.

-1. I wanted to turn off and on the pivot prices displayed above the candles. Just for the visibility sake once in a while. And the following changes to the function doesn't do anything:

```
//@version=4
study(title="testmajiggy", overlay=true)

// I've defined the switch "pvhl" on for the pivot high low here. 

pvhl = input(true, title="pivot hl on")
lenH = input(title="Length High", type=input.integer, defval=100, minval=1)
lenL = input(title="Length Low", type=input.integer, defval=100, minval=1)

// then put it in as an argument for the function "fun" down here. I'm not sure if I did it right... 

fun(pvhl, src, len, isHigh, _style, _yloc, _color) =>
    pvhl
    p = nz(src[len])
    isFound = true
    for i = 0 to len - 1
        if isHigh and src[i] > p
            isFound := false

        if not isHigh and src[i] < p
            isFound := false

    for i = len + 1 to 2 * len
        if isHigh and src[i] >= p
            isFound := false

        if not isHigh and src[i] <= p
            isFound := false

    if isFound
        label.new(bar_index[len], p, tostring(p), style=_style, yloc=_yloc, color=_color)

//then I made sure the "fun" call included the pvhl argument in here. 

fun(pvhl, high, lenH, true, label.style_labeldown, yloc.abovebar, color.white)
fun(pvhl, low, lenL, false, label.style_labelup, yloc.belowbar, color.white)
```

Shouldn't that pvhl switch give me the option to turn off or on the function fun? It gives me the option to tick on or off but it does nothing.

-2. How do I change the offset distance of the label up there? Changing yloc.abovebar to have options throws errors. I would like to change it because when the chart is in autofit, many of the prices are below the cutoff and do not show. It would be nice if the price labels were some fraction of the distance of the default.(whatever the default is, and however you find out)

thanks for any tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simpler to keep the condition out of the function. Also, would be faster to just hide the indicator with the *Show/Hide* eye icon when you don't want it to show.

```
//@version=4
study(title="testmajiggy", overlay=true)

pvhl = input(true, title="pivot hl on")
lenH = input(title="Length High", type=input.integer, defval=100, minval=1)
lenL = input(title="Length Low", type=input.integer, defval=100, minval=1)
atrM = input(0.5, "Price Offset (Multiple of ATR)", minval = 0.0, step = 0.1)
atrD = atr(5) * atrM

fun(src, len, isHigh, _style, _yloc, _color, _offset) =>
    p = nz(src[len])
    isFound = true
    for i = 0 to len - 1
        if isHigh and src[i] > p
            isFound := false

        if not isHigh and src[i] < p
            isFound := false

    for i = len + 1 to 2 * len
        if isHigh and src[i] >= p
            isFound := false

        if not isHigh and src[i] <= p
            isFound := false

    if isFound
        label.new(bar_index[len], p + _offset, tostring(p), style=_style, yloc=_yloc, color=_color)

if pvhl
    fun(high, lenH, true, label.style_labeldown, yloc.price, color.white, atrD)
    fun(low, lenL, false, label.style_labelup, yloc.price, color.white, -atrD)
```

Comment: ok. thank you. i don't understand why you have to use the ATR but i think it has to do with how the label is placed near the chart and i guess the way pinescript does it is using the price? but atr calculation is so complicated, why not just use a certain points or percent? would that make the calculation go faster in pinescript?

Comment: Notice that `yloc.price` is now used. With this type of positioning of the label, we need a precise price level to position the label, whereas the previously used `yloc.abovebar` and `yloc.belowbar` didn't.
The advantage of calculating the offest as a multiple of ATR is that it makes it more generic. It will work on more types of charts than a percentage of price, although if you only use charts with prices in the same range, you could also use a percentage of price. And no, the ATR calc doesn't really slow down the indicator.

Comment: o yeah I forgot to ask. the reason i wanted to turn off the function is so that i don't use tradingview's time and resource calculating the function if i have it turned off. is there a way to do that? I tried the `fun(src, len, isHigh, _style, _yloc, _color, offset) => pvhl? "the rest of the fucntion here then" : na` And that throws error saying " syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation"

Comment: Because your code is v4, `fun()` currently won't be executed when `pvhl` is set to `false`, but if you really want to reduce server load, then hiding the indicator on the chart is the best thing to do.

Comment: i have it set as a part of another indicator, so if i turn off the view using eye icon, i hide the moving averages also. i only have free account and i'm only allowed 3 indicators. so this is one way i can get more indicators on my chart.